# Modify two xml files with python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, xml-parsing

```
 1. xml 1

 <item-groups>
      <item-group>
        <items type="array">
          <item>
            <type>PRODUCT</type>
            <product>D</product>
            <ordered-quantity type="integer">1</ordered-quantity>
            <options type="array">
              <option>
                <name>UNIQUE.ID</name>
                <value type="integer">17757538</value>
              </option>
              <option>
                <name>DR.GLS.CMG</name>
                <value>BL</value>
              </option>
              <option>
                <name>DR.CLR.I.OE</name>
                <value>SBL</value>
              </option>
              <option>
                <name>HDL.PITCHER</name>
                <value>N</value>
              </option>
              <option>
                <name>SR.OPT</name>
                <value>N</value>
              </option>
              <option>
                <name>HNG.TYPE.OE</name>
                <value>STDH</value>
              </option>
            </options>
          </item>
          <item>
            <type>PRODUCT</type>
            <product>Dynasty Series</product>
            <ordered-quantity type="integer">1</ordered-quantity>
            <options type="array">
              <option>
                <name>Install Type</name>
                <value>RE</value>
              </option>
            </options>
          </item>
        </items>
      </item-group>
    </item-groups>
```

xml 1 is the file that i want to modify with the `<options>` of xml2

```
  xml 2
           <options type="array">
              <option>
                <name>Window height</name>
                <value type="integer">1234</value>
              </option>
              <option>
                <name>Frame Color</name>
                <value>Black</value>
              </option>
              <option>
                <name>Low e</name>
                <value>obscure low e</value>
              </option>
              <option>
                <name>Grid</name>
                <value>Contour Grid</value>
              </option>
             <option>
           </options>
```

XML2 should be the body of XML1 , i have this two in two diferet files i`m able to read  both of them but can`t find a way how to modify the fist xml. and options should change

basically i wan`t that the child in root.iter('option') to get the values from pure_data = [] but only for the first` option type = 'array'  not the second one

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import pandas as pd
    tree = ET.parse('xml2.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()                                                          
    blueprint_tree = ET.parse('xml1.xml')
    blueprint_root = blueprint_tree.getroot()
    data_extract = []
    pure_data = []
    for child in root.iter('option'):
        name = child.find('name').text
        value = child.find('value').text 
        items= {}
        items['name'] = name
        items['value'] = value
        data_extract.append(items)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_extract)  
    pure_data = []
    for option in blueprint_root.iter('option'):
        nkey = option.find('name').text
        vkey = option.find('value').text
        i= {}
        i['name'] = nkey
        i['value'] = vkey
        pure_data.append(i)
    
    
    print(data_extract)

    print(pure_data)
```

please share your thoughts or a guidance of what method should i use

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the first `options` element should work

```
first_opts = root.find('.//options)
for child in first_opts.iter('option'):
    # name/value stuff
```

Comment: this doesn`t help me mutch , i am ccessing the elemt`s , i just need no modify the value on the first <option> with the values that i have stored in pure_data = []

Comment: @a.cuko according to the question: `but only for the first option type = 'array' not the second one`. The answer does that, works only on the first `options` element. You should apply it accordingly to the first or second XML

Comment: undertood as i said i know how to access the first option , what i want is how to manipulate the data , basically i want to clear the options from the first xml1 and give the options of xml2